# linux driver's function known/visible to application

Tags: linux, dll, drivers, ioctl

In windows we create a function in a driver and we can call it from the application using dll as the middle man.  What happens in linux?  How can we create a custom function (ioctl) for example and call/ use it from the host application?

Any suggestions, insights, examples, links would be great.

Answer (score 1):

[this blog post](http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/08/writing-linux-device-driver-for-kernels.html) seems to have a nice run-through of writing a device driver in general. ioctl is not specifically mentioned in that post, but the post itself points to the public availability of a book "[Linux Device Drivers, 3rd edition](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/)", which contains a chapter on ioctl usage as well.

Answer (score 1):

The header files are sufficient for making a driver's function visible to application